# bandwidth for a chirp spread spectrum

Tags: digital-communications

For a PSK communication with a symbole time $T$, the bandwidth of the system is $B=\frac{1} {T}$.

But for a chirp spread spectrum with the same symbol time $T$ and  the bandwidth of the chirp is $B_c$. What is the bandwidth of the system?

Answer (score 1):

(Note that all of these expressions are approximations)

For a PSK waveform with symbol time $T$, it is true that the bandwidth $B \approx 1/T$.  The exact relationship depends on the pulse shape.

For a [chirp spread spectrum (CSS) system](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7797659), the bandwidth of the chirp $B_c = f_{\max} - f_{\min}$ is approximately the bandwidth of the system.  The symbols are defined by what frequency $f_0$ in the range $[f_{\min}, f_{\max}]$ each chirp starts. (The instantaneous frequency "wraps around" to $f_\min$ once it gets to $f_\max$.)